# Select one value of one colum of an array obtained with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code :

```
$foo = $bdd->prepare($qry);
$foo->execute();
$result = $foo->fetchAll();
```

In `$qry`, i have a `SELECT` with a `JOIN` between tables `beatles b` et `status s` (on the columns `status_id`), such that the result is the following :

Code :

```
b.id    b.firstname    b.lastname    b.status_id   s.status_id     s.status

0       John           Lennon        0             0               Mort
1       Paul           McCartney     1             1               Vivant
2       Ringo          Starr         1             1               Vivant
3       George         Harrison      0             0               Mort
```

(The first line is the columns' names in the tables, it isn't inside the result of the query)

I want to select in php only the `s.status` of ringo starr, for instance. How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: select in PHP? Why not alter the query with a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Dont be coy, show your actual query, its relevant

Comment: I don't have any actual query, as what I was looking for is a way to select any one particular value of the output array, keeping the output array as it is (as I might need to select other values in it). @d0ug7a5 answered my question perfectly. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the value of status for Ringo Starr, but need the values of the other fields within that page, then (assuming the array has come back indexed by id), you could access it with `$result[2]['status']`. Otherwise, change your select statement to just select the values of `id` and `status`.

As a side note, in your SELECT statement you'll need to give aliases potentially for the `b.status_id` and `s.status_id`; when you join, the column names are taken and the table names basically ignored in terms of what is returned - so something like `b.status_id AS b_status_id, s.status_id AS s_status_id` would make sure you got the correct values for both of these. You may have done this already of course - it just looked as though you might have not, judging from the column names you gave.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to just pick one column from the existing result or issue a query that will get you only what you want. But a better defined query sound the most sensible

```
SELECT 
  [ your joins etc ]

WHERE b.firstname = 'Ringo'
  AND b.lastname = 'Starr'
```

Or if you want to just get the Ringo Starr entry from your existing result

```
foreach ( $resultats as $result ) {
    if ( $result['firstname'] == 'Ringo' && $result['lastname'] == 'Starr' ) {
        echo 'Got him';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add WHERE clause with condition that satisfy your needs
2. alter fields clause leaving only one you need
3. use `fetchColumn()` instead of `fetchAll()`
4. You're set.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but based on the demonstrated abilities of the questioner, your answer is not actually very helpful.